# Show Inventory command on Cisco

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands

Could someone please confirm if 'show inventory' command works on 'IOS (tm) C3560 Software (C3560-I9-M), Version 12.1(19)EA1d'? If no, what is version and upwards do I need this to get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need this sort of information, you can search on Cisco's web site. It is in [Cisco IOS Configuration Fundamentals Command Reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/fundamentals/command/cf_command_ref/show_gsr_through_show_monitor_event_trace.html#wp3909457221):

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, which means according to this the command doesn't support on my device :(

Comment: It means it isn't supported on your IOS version.